# NLP Human Generated Captions

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, wikipedia

I need good quality human generated captions. How can I query the captions stored by Wikipedia. Example return all captions containing the word helicopter

Comment: Please add more details of what you've tried so far. Include, the code and procedure. Did you scrape the Wikipedia page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include the source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Nikhil...I do not know where to begin with this....querying the captions...I need data, human generated captions. Do you know how I can query the wikicommons captions

Comment: What do you mean by "querying the captions"? Do you mean you want to extract text related to caption from wikipedia/wikicommons webpage?

Comment: I need human generated captions. So I want to extract as many human generated captions as possible which contain the word helicopter. I presume that wiki has a huge number of images but I am not interested in the images but I am interested in the captions. So i want to download all the captions from wikipedia containing the word helicopter

Comment: @Nikhil - It's obvious that OP wants to query some information from wikipedia. I don't see a problem here.  Give her a break.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi It is not OBVIOUS. That's why I was asking for clarity so I could help out if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't query Wikipedia captions (you could, of course, screen-scrape them). Wikimedia Commons has some amount of machine-readable captions though (it is [in the process](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Structured_data) of transitioning to a more structured data format) but dumps are not available yet (see [T221917](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T221917) and [T174031](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T174031)) so you probably wouldn't be any better off using those.

If you don't need a huge amount of data, you could check Commons' Picture of the Day, for which the captions are stored at a separate page with a predictable name, `Template:Potd/YYYY-MM-DD_(LL)` (e.g. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Template:Potd/2020-05-01_(en)). You'll still have to do some lightweight wikitext or HTML parsing though.

Comment: Thank you thats a start